# How do i connect to Unix File System which is in Different Remote servers

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to place a file in UNIX file system from local desktop using Excel VBA, which is in remote server,which is in another Remote Server.
Problem Statement: 
First I have to connect to Remote Server 1 and then i need to connect Remote Server-2 which is in Remote Server-1. 
The Unix server is in Remote Server -2.

Please let me know possibilities of connecting to Unix Server from my local desktop using Excel VBA.

Thanks,
DEEPAK

Answer (score 0):

Quite a confusing setup but your "server in a server"... is it a virtual server? If so, your admin should have set it up to have its own resources and network access so you don't have to access one inside another. You just connect to the server you need.

If you are connecting to the UNIX server from a Windows machine your admin should have installed and configured SAMBA so you can then access files through Windows Explorer.

I've made an assumption at the beginning because I'm unsure of your precise configuration as I've never heard of a server in a server unless you're talking about a virtual server, but these are usually seen as individual servers that can be directly connected to...

Comment: No, Both are physical servers only.

Usually we do connect manually from Windows desktop. I just wanted automate this process. Since moving a file from Desktop to Remote Server-1 and From 1 to Remote Server 2 will take long time.

Comment: So your setup is: YOU => Server1 => Server2 and you can only connect via Server1?

Comment: OK, you've updated your answer. Is there a specific block as to why your desktop computer can't connect directly to Server2?

Comment: The Remote Server-2 can be connected only from Remoter Server-1 Network (restrictions). I dont have specific answer for Why?. I cannot directly connect to Remote Server -2.

Comment: Are both servers UNIX? (not a huge problem if they're mixed)... You could set up a symlink or junction from Server1 to Server2 so that your script is tricked into thinking it is saving to Server1 but (behind the scenes) the Server1 junction seamlessly puts the file into Server2.

Comment: If your servers are UNIX you could try SSHFS

Comment: They both are just remote desktops. The actual UNIX Server(where I wanted to place a file) is in Remote Server -2.

Comment: You could create a cron job on your UNIX server to copy your file from the Windows server 'it' can communicate with, at a regular interval so all you need to do is save the file to the Windows server you have access to (using UNC)?

Comment: I am not sure if i can do that. The reason why i am preferring VBA Macro. I need to generate a output file using the inputs given then i directly push it to the Server.

Comment: By using "remote desktop" you are not automating anything and making extra work for yourself in the long run. The only way to automate your task is to have a way of saving your file via a network share to your "Server1" but because you have no direct access to Server2 via a network share you either remote desktop and manually copy the file or have a task on either of the servers that will copy the file to your Server2. Two ways: a cron/scheduled task or an application on Server1 that constantly monitors your directory and the moment your file is updated copies it to server 2

Answer (score 0):

This may answer your question
check it out here:

http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/howto/linux/system/using-pipe-and-ssh-to-connect-commands-between-different-unix-hosts-output-local-cat-less-etc-into-remote-files-grep-or-watch-remote-logs

Comment: This is a link only response ... put the relevant details in the response